# Adding a widget into QGroupBox

Tags: pyqt, widget, qgroupbox

I am trying to add a QPushButton widget into a QGroupBox such as:

```
self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Push Button')
self.grp_box = QtGui.QGroupBox('Button Section')
self.grp_box.addWidget(self.btn)
```

When trying to run the code, I got this error : `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'addWidget'`

After some online checking, it seems that QGroupBox only allows `setLayout`, meaning I will need to use `QVBoxLayout` or `QHBoxLayout` etc.

Is there anyway to get around this, adding in a widget without the use of any layout(s)? I am using PyQt.

Comment: No. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: For categorizing and make the ui pretty?

Comment: Why would you **not** want to use a layout?

Comment: I am not sure if this can be done without the use of layout. Also, say if I only have a pushbutton, I am not seeing the point that I need to add this button into a layout then onto a groupBox (this is just me saying..) and hence I am asking

Comment: Make the button a child of the group-box. It should then appear by default in the top-left corner of the group-box - but will probably obscure its title. So then you will need to give the button an absolute position (e.g. `button.move(20, 20)`). However, if the group-box changes size, it could also obscure the button, so you will need to set a minimum size for the group-box, etc, etc. Of course, the whole point of layouts is to avoid having to deal with all these tedious details and allow Qt to manage it all automatically.

Answer (score 3):

First create your main layout = QHBoxLayout()

```
  main_layout = QHBoxLayout()
```

Then create the group box:

```
  group_box = QGroupBox("Group Box")
```

Create the group box layout:

```
  group_box_layout = QVBoxLayout()
```

Add widgets to the group box layout like this:

```
  group_box_layout.addWidget(QCheckBox("Check Box 1"))
  group_box_layout.addWidget(QCheckBox("Check Box 2"))
  group_box_layout.addWidget(QCheckBox("Check Box 3"))
```

Assign the group box layout to the group box:

```
  group_box.setLayout(group_box_layout)
```

Assing the group box to the main layout:

```
  main_layout.addWidget(group_box)
```

And add this at the end:

```
    widget = QWidget()
    widget.setLayout(layout1)
    self.setCentralWidget(widget)
```